# Retrieve records above and below a specific record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I often verify logs in SQLServer and my query usually looks like this (where Type = 0 means error):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Logs 
WHERE Type = 0 
ORDER BY Timestamp
```

But most of the time, I'm not only interested by the error itself but also at what happened immediately before the error.

Is it possible, with SQLServer, to query n lines above/under (relative to the primary key) each line matching the WHERE clause of the query?

Ex. With my query I would only get lines 125 & 130. I would like [123, 124, 125] and [128, 129, 130].

```
PrimaryKey  Timestamp             Type  Description
123         2012-09-17 03:41:46.240 1   Working.
124         2012-09-17 03:42:46.240 1   Database backup.
125         2012-09-17 03:43:46.240 0   Access violation.
126         2012-09-17 03:44:46.240 1   Working.
127         2012-09-17 03:45:46.240 1   Working.
128         2012-09-17 03:46:46.240 1   Working.
129         2012-09-17 03:47:46.240 1   Backup.
130         2012-09-17 03:48:46.240 0   Corrupted.
131         2012-09-17 03:49:46.240 1   Working.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it as follows:

```
SELECT 
    L2.* 
FROM 
    Logs L1
    JOIN Logs L2
    ON 
        L1.PrimaryKey = L2.PrimaryKey OR 
        L1.PrimaryKey = L2.PrimaryKey - 1 OR
        L1.PrimaryKey = L2.PrimaryKey + 1
WHERE
    L1.Type = 0
```

The results would be as follows:

```
PrimaryKey  TS                      Type        Description
----------- ----------------------- ----------- -----------------
124         2012-09-17 03:42:46.240 1           Database backup.
125         2012-09-17 03:43:46.240 0           Access violation.
126         2012-09-17 03:44:46.240 1           Working.
129         2012-09-17 03:47:46.240 1           Backup.
130         2012-09-17 03:48:46.240 0           Corrupted.
131         2012-09-17 03:49:46.240 1           Working.
```

You can modify the join conditions using the relational operators to retrieve `n` lines above and below the matching line.

If the PrimaryKey column is not guaranteed to be sequential, then assuming that the records are always ordered by `Timestamp` in `ASC` order, the following query will fetch the before and after records to a selected one:

```
WITH LogsTable (PrimaryKey, TS, Type, Description, Rank) AS
(
    SELECT 
        PrimaryKey, 
        TS, 
        Type, 
        Description, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TS ASC) as 'Rank' 
    FROM 
        Logs
)
SELECT 
    L2.* 
FROM 
    LogsTable L1
    JOIN LogsTable L2
    ON 
        L1.Rank = L2.Rank OR 
        L1.Rank = L2.Rank - 1 OR
        L1.Rank = L2.Rank + 1
WHERE
    L1.Type = 0
```

Comment: Thank you Vikdor, that's exaclty what I was looking for!

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the IDs are guaranteed sequential though. An `IDENTITY` column does not guarantee this.

Comment: @MartinSmith, you are right. I was assuming that IDs would be sequential. If not, then we should use the `RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TS ASC)` and use the rank to identify the record below and above a selected one. Updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Using `RANK()` on `TS` seems like it might cause issues when `TS` has duplicate values that would end up with the same rank value. Maybe `ROW_NUMBER()`?